# How do I get background-image to display on my github page?

Tags: html, css, github-pages

## Summarize

I tried getting the video.gif to display in the background on the github page, but it only displayed locally for some reason. Been working on this for over 2 hrs and still could not get it to work.

## Here is what I've tried so far.

```
+ background-image: url("../gifs/video.gif"); - Doesn't work
+ background-image: url('../gifs/video.gif'); - Doesn't work
+ background-image: url('https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/JackTimelessPiece/Website/master/gifs/video.gif'); - Work Locally
+ background-image: url('gifs/video/gif'); - Work Locally
```

## Here is my current css code

```
body {
    background-image: 
url('https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/JackTimelessPiece/Website/master/gifs/video.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height 

    }
```

## My results

I only got the `url('gifs/video.gif')` and `url('https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/JackTimelessPiece/Website/master/gifs/video.gif')` to work locally and they will not work on github page for some reason.

## Update

Apparently I just moved the background-image codes to the index.html and somehow it fix the gifs to load up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://jacktimelesspiece.github.io/Website/styles.css redirects to https://jacktimelesspiece.com/styles.css, which has background-image: url('../gifs/video.gif');, and styles.css is already in the root directory, so that won't work.
Also, https://jacktimelesspiece.com/gifs/video.gif returns text.

Comment: So how should I approach this problem? As you can see from my current css post, I used a different url that shows the gif with no problem :/

Comment: The GIF on https://jacktimelesspiece.com/ is working fine here. Your `github.io` URLs are redirecting there because of [this file](https://github.com/JackTimelessPiece/Website/blob/master/CNAME) in your repo.